How to remove the blue outline from MUI Autocomplete TextField?

<Autocomplete
                {...{ className }}
                multiple
                options={options}
                value={value}
                onChange={handleOnChange}
                id="tags-standard"
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        sx={{
                            '& .MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused': {
                                border: 'none', // fixed extra hover
                                outline: 'none',
                                
                        }, 
                           }}
                        label="Search or add new tags"
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                        onInput={handleInputChange}
                        value={inputValue}
                        InputProps={{
                            ...params.InputProps,
                            endAdornment: (
                                <>
                                    {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                                    <Button onClick={handleAddNewOption}>Add</Button>
                                </>
                            )
                        }}
                    />
                )}
            />

I have tried the sx={} here but to no avail.
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="tags-standard" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused mui-theme-152mnda-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" type="text" value="" data-last-active-input="">


Turns out this fixed the issue, it was actually border-shadow:
#tags-standard:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}


it's work for me
sx={{
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
        borderColor: "black",
    },
}}


Where did you put that exactly? I am talking about the blue input inside the Big Input.
